# Visual studio watch window not allowing to type

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging my application. When I open watch window and click on new row to write variable name it shows error. Please see the image.

[image]

It creates a file "VisualStudio_Debugger_Intellisense_1880_13" and file contains nothing. I restarted Visual studio but didn't worked.

Comment: I found the problem. It was due to a extension "Where Am I", disabled that extension, and now everything working fine.

Comment: You can write this information as answer and check as answer, it helps somebody else. This comment is not noticeable and question looks still unanswered in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was due to a extension "Where Am I". Where Am I extension is available for Visual Studio 2010. This is not available for VS 2012. I did a hack so that it can be installed on VS 2012. This caused this problem. I disabled that extension, and now everything working fine.